# Render the binding value in dynamic generated html template in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

For following code: I want the "test1 span" could be changed with javascript. How can I do it? NOTE: the {{msg}} maybe from ajax output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- app -->
        <div id="app">
            <span v-html="test"></span>
            <span v-html="test1"></span>
            {{test3}}
        </div>
        <script>
            var app1 = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    test: '<p style="color: red">THIS IS HTML</p>',
                    test1: '{{msg}}',
                    test3: 20,
                    msg: 10
                }
            })

            function change() {
                app1.msg = Math.random()
                app1.test3 = Math.random()
            }
            setInterval(change, 2000)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Modification**:
Maybe I need to make my question clear:
For next modify code, when launch the page, you will see `Go to Foo` link in the page, then you click the link, you will see `hello {{msg}}`
**NOTE**: this comes from the remote server: `b.html`.
I set a timer there, every 2 seconds, change the value of `msg`, I wish the `{{msg}}` in page could change to a random number.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue-router/2.7.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <p>
            <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
            </p>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>

        <script>
            const Foo = {
                template: '<div v-html="template1"></div>',

                data: function () {
                    return {
                        template1: null
                    }
                },
                created: function () {
                    this.fetchData()
                },
                watch: {
                    '$route': 'fetchData'
                },
                methods: {
                    fetchData () {
                        var that = this
                        $.get("http://localhost/try/b.html", function(data, status) {
                            that.template1 = data
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            const routes = [
            { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
            ]

            const router = new VueRouter({
                routes
            })

            const app = new Vue({
                router
            }).$mount('#app')

            function change() {
                app.msg = Math.random()
            }
            setInterval(change, 2000)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```
<div>
    hello
    {{msg}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to evaluate the answers given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the answer from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-compile)

> Vue.compile( template )

this will make the template from remote server be parsed again by vuejs.

***main.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue-router/2.7.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <p>
            <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
            </p>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>

        <script>
            const Foo = {
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        template1: null,
                        msg: null
                    }
                },
                created: function () {
                    this.fetchData()
                    setInterval(this.change, 2000)
                },

                render: function(createElement) {
                    if (this.template1)
                    {
                        return this.template1();
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    change() {
                        this.msg = Math.random()
                    },

                    fetchData () {
                        var that = this
                        $.get("http://localhost/try/b.html", function(data, status) {
                            that.template1 = Vue.compile(data).render
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            const routes = [
            { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
            ]

            const router = new VueRouter({
                routes
            })

            const app1 = new Vue({
                router
            }).$mount('#app')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***b.html***

```
<div>
    hello
    {{msg}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools that Vue.js gives you. Put `change()` in your VM's `methods` object, then create a `created()` hook that sets up the interval.

Please note that `v-html` expects a `String`, not a `Number`, so just add `.toString()` when generating the random number.

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: '<p style="color: red">THIS IS HTML</p>',
    test1: null,
    test3: 20,
    msg: 10
  },
  watch: {
    msg: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.test1 = newVal
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.msg = Math.random().toString()
      this.test3 = Math.random()
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(this.change, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-html="test"></span>
  <span v-html="test1"></span>
  {{ test3 }}
</div>
```

Instead of a watcher it is even easier to go for a computed property instead.

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: '<p style="color: red">THIS IS HTML</p>',
    test3: 20,
    msg: 10
  },
  computed: {
    test1() {
      return this.msg.toString()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.msg = Math.random()
      this.test3 = Math.random()
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(this.change, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-html="test"></span>
  <span v-html="test1"></span> 
  {{ test3 }}
</div>
```

Comment: where is {{msg}}, my procedure is as follows, when page load, it will first try to ajax.get a static html page from server, the content of this this static html page is {{msg}}, this is just a template; after the template ready, the page will get data content periodically from the server, and I want vuejs to replace the {{msg}} with new data content. So I should see {{msg}} in the code.

Comment: Instead you see {{test1}} in the code which returns msg as soon as msg changes.

Comment: I change the question to explain my question better.

Comment: As I said, `{{test1}}` will update the HTML with the new content of `msg` any time `msg` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use v-model instead of v-html :-

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        test: '<p style="color: red">THIS IS HTML</p>',
        test1: '{{msg}}',
        test3: 20,
        msg: 10
    }
})

function change() {
    app1.msg = Math.random()
    app1.test3 = Math.random()
}
setInterval(change, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            <span v-html="test"></span>
            <span v-model="test1">{{msg}}</span>
            {{test3}}
        </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it not works on myside; I can just see test(with red color) & test3(change with random number) works, but can not see test1 completely.

Comment: Strange, when I directly run code snippet in stackoverflow, it seems works, but not works on my local, I will double check.

Comment: seems you replace <span v-model="test1">{{msg}}</span> in div, my original purpose is as follows, When the page start, it will use ajax to get a static html page from server, it may get the content: {{msg}}, then it will put this html fragment in html through vuejs binding; after get the {{msg}} from web server, I will load real data from another server, I want vuejs to replace {{msg}} with new data. So the div part can not know {{msg}} at first. See my modified question.

Comment: I want first get a html fragment, maybe table from remote, then I get the data, I want vuejs expand the table with my data to serval rows. In fact, if the html fragment is just written in advance in main html, it is ok for vuejs to expand with new data; but here, my html fragment is from remote server, that means when vuejs first render html page, my html fragment is not exist there.

Comment: I see a similar usage for "mesos web monitor", but they use angularJS, I want to do same things with VueJS.

Comment: See my modified question, I wish html template & html real data comes from different servers, and vuejs could expand html template with html real data. But at first, the main page do not know what html template is, is it possible to realize it in Vuejs?

Comment: I change the question to more explain my question better.